# How to clear a specific WordPress endpoint cache PHP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I used the below code to clear the whole cache but that is not a solution I want to clear only specific api endpoint cache this is what I'm using that clear everything

```
wp_cache_flush();
```